# JavaScript runtime error: The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using some jQuery stuff, on my site and it references the Google API libs, though there seem to be many problems with the file being referenced. Is there a more stable version of this file? Or, are we legally allowed to download this particular file, and modify it so that it stops screwing up?

As you can see, Visual Studio outputs trillions of lines to the console:

> 0x8000000a - JavaScript runtime error: The data necessary to complete
>   this operation is not yet available. Exception was thrown at line 16,
>   column 49860 in
>   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js
>   0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError Exception was
>   thrown at line 16, column 50063

Answer (score 0):

IANAL but you can download the jquery code from the jquery site. I do not think that will solve your real problem though as I suspect it is in your code.